# Read more button shows incorrect information

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two testimonials on a page. I have read more buttons under the text.

The left button works fine and does exactly as I want it to.

However, the right button shows more text from the left testimonial instead of the right.

I'm not sure why this is and nothing is complaining to me in the console.

Please visit: clientsforcounsellors.com and scroll down to see the testimonials I'm referring to.

Left testimonial:

```
<!-- Quotation -->
                <p class="test-paragraph dark-grey-text mt-4"><i class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2"></i>"Harrison has been continually knowledgeable, patient, professional, and overall a fantastic help. He is clearly well informed in the digital marketing and web design field.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="read-more"> He always gives timely responses which are clear and helpful. The finished site looks professional and inviting – just what I wanted. I will recommend him to my colleagues. Thanks again, Harri."</span></p>
                <button onclick="readMore()" class="read-more-btn">Read More</button>
```

Right testimonial:

```
<p class="test-paragraph dark-grey-text mt-4"><i class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2"></i>"Harrison has been continually knowledgeable, patient, professional, and overall a fantastic help. He is clearly well informed in the digital marketing and web design field.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="read-more"> He always gives timely responses which are clear and helpful. The finished site looks professional and inviting – just what I wanted. I will recommend him to my colleagues. Thanks again, Harri."</span></p>
                <button onclick="readMore()" class="read-more-btn">Read More</button>
```

```
.read-more {
    display: none;
}
```

```
<script>

        var testParagraph = document.querySelectorAll(".test-paragraph");
        var i;
    
        for (i = 0; i < testParagraph.length; i++) {

          function readMore() {

          var dots = document.querySelector(".dots");
          var moreText = document.querySelector(".read-more");
          var btnText = document.querySelector(".read-more-btn");

          if (dots.style.display === "none") {
              dots.style.display = "inline";
              btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
              moreText.style.display = "none";
          } else {
              dots.style.display = "none";
              btnText.innerHTML = "Read Less";
              moreText.style.display = "inline";
            }
          }
        }

      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a

```js
const readMore = () => {
  const btn = event.target;
  const paragraph = btn.previousElementSibling;

  const dots = paragraph.querySelector(".dots");
  const moreText = paragraph.querySelector(".read-more");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btn.innerText = "Read More";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btn.innerText = "Read Less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
.read-more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Quotation -->
<p class="test-paragraph dark-grey-text mt-4"><i class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2"></i>"Harrison has been continually knowledgeable, patient, professional, and overall a fantastic help. He is clearly well informed in the digital marketing and web design field.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="read-more"> He always gives timely responses which are clear and helpful. The finished site looks professional and inviting – just what I wanted. I will recommend him to my colleagues. Thanks again, Harri."</span></p>
<button onclick="readMore()" class="read-more-btn">Read More</button>


<p class="test-paragraph dark-grey-text mt-4"><i class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2"></i>"Harrison has been continually knowledgeable, patient, professional, and overall a fantastic help. He is clearly well informed in the digital marketing and web design field.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="read-more"> He always gives timely responses which are clear and helpful. The finished site looks professional and inviting – just what I wanted. I will recommend him to my colleagues. Thanks again, Harri."</span></p>
<button onclick="readMore()" class="read-more-btn">Read More</button>
```

previous sibling like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend declaring javascript events inside tags like this:

```
<button onclick="readMore()"...
```

And as my long practice has shown, this is bad. And I want to show a solution in which you can achieve the desired result using the `forEach()` method, as well as using the `toggle()` method to switch the `read-more` class. Look at the code.

```js
var btnText = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more-btn");
var moreText = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more");
var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dots");

btnText.forEach(function(current_btn, index) {
    current_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      moreText[index].classList.toggle("read-more");
      
      if (dots[index].style.display == "none") {
        dots[index].style.display = "inline";
      } else {
        dots[index].style.display = "none";
      }

      if (current_btn.innerText == "Read More") {
        current_btn.innerText = "Read Less";
      } else {
        current_btn.innerText = "Read More";
      }
            
    });
});
```

```css
.read-more {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="test-paragraph dark-grey-text mt-4"><i class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2"></i>"Harrison has been continually
    knowledgeable, patient, professional, and overall a fantastic help. He is clearly well informed in the digital
    marketing and web design field.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="read-more"> He always gives timely
        responses which are clear and helpful. The finished site looks professional and inviting – just what I wanted. I
        will recommend him to my colleagues. Thanks again, Harri."</span></p>
<button class="read-more-btn">Read More</button>

<p class="test-paragraph dark-grey-text mt-4"><i class="fas fa-quote-left pr-2"></i>"Harrison has been continually
    knowledgeable, patient, professional, and overall a fantastic help. He is clearly well informed in the digital
    marketing and web design field.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="read-more"> He always gives timely
        responses which are clear and helpful. The finished site looks professional and inviting – just what I wanted. I
        will recommend him to my colleagues. Thanks again, Harri."</span></p>
<button class="read-more-btn">Read More</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Why would you not recommend declaring JavaScript functions inside of onclick?

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves, `1` - lack of clarity and structuredness of the code; `2` - сannot raise multiple events per element; `3` - by writing an event to a tag, you lose the ability to use an event object of the Event type, which provides additional capabilities; `4` - when cloning elements via JS, events written in tags will be cloned, which does not happen when cloning nodes with events added via JS. and etc...

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves, and these are not all examples of bad practice using an event inside a tag.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` choose only one element if there is other elements. It's different to `getElementsByClassName` which get all elements to an array. So when using `querySelector` then it choose only one:

```js
 var dots = document.querySelector(".dots"); // one .dots element from all .dots elements
 var moreText = document.querySelector(".read-more"); // one .read-more element from the class
 var btnText = document.querySelector(".read-more-btn"); // one .read-more-btn from the class
```

So when `readMore()` function is activated, the first element of two elements(Gloria between Gloria and Tommy) is chosen.

To choose both elements in `for` loop, using `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll` will be helpful.

```js
        for (i = 0; i < testParagraph.length; i++) {

          function readMore() {

            var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dots")[i];
            var moreText = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more")[i];
            var btnText = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more-btn")[i];

... 
}
```